# How to set up RewriteRule from another server user?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There are two domains on the same server, I need to selectively display content from one page to another. It seems to me that the most correct option is Apache rewrites. I managed to implement this at the level of one domain:

```
RewriteRule    "^test_rewrite\.php$"  "../path/page/" [PT]
```

but I can't display content from another (
example.com/test/test_rewrite.php should output the content of anotherexample.com/path1/page1.php
).

I tried to specify an alias for another user, but the server returns a 500 error.
how to implement it correctly?

Comment: AS flag PT seems work only for internal rewriting, you may require a Redirect rewriring to an external server.

Comment: Do you want the browser address bar to remain example.com?  Then setup a proxy.  If you do not mind that the domain in the browser address bar changes, setup a redirection.

Comment: I need to leave example.com in the browser bar, but display content from example2.com.

Comment: I thought using mod_rewrite it is impossible to replace content from another server (in my case, both sites are on the same server)?

Comment: How can I implement a proxy?